# How to increase filedescriptor's range in python select()

Tags: python, sockets, select, file-descriptor

I test python socket programming. And Modify the options as shown below was in Mac

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

**But The following error has occurred.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssub.py", line 63, in createMqttClient
    rc = mqttc.loop()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mosquitto.py", line 633, in loop
    socklist = select.select(rlist, wlist, [], timeout)
**ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()**
```

increase the filedescriptor how to write `select ()` function?

Answer (score 7):

There is a limit to the number of file descriptors that `select()` supports - the easiest solution is to simply use [poll()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll) instead, which doesn't suffer from this limit.

Strictly speaking, `select()` is limited in the highest file descriptor it can support, as opposed to the number of them in a given call - see the start of the **Notes** section of the [select() manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html). I'm not sure what `FD_SETSIZE` is on OSX, but on Linux it's 1024. There's no practical way to increase this limit from Python.

As an aside, if you want to keep things portable you might consider using something like [pyev](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyev/) which is a Python wrapper around `libev` library which uses the optimal method of waiting for IO on a given platform.

Comment: Note:  Under Windows, the limitation is different -- under Windows, it is the number of descriptors, not the value of the largest descriptor, that matters.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Come to think of it I'm not *entirely* sure there isn't a way to fiddle with the limit on Windows, but I'm not aware of one. It might be handy as I don't believe `poll()` is available on Windows.

Comment: Modern versions of Windows do have WSAPoll(), which is more or less the same thing as poll()...

Comment: Use to know about, but it's annoying to have to put any OS-specific code into Python applications (although I do realise it's sometimes unavoidable). Unless you meant that Python's `select` module has been updated to use `WSAPoll()`?

Comment: I haven't tested it myself, but hopefully Python's select.poll() method would call through to WSAPoll() on versions of Windows that have WSAPoll()...